# Mongodb Tableau | BI Connector, $lookup query SQL Syntax - Left Outer Join

Tags: mysql, mongodb, aggregation-framework, left-join, tableau-api

I'm trying to implement the $lookup query SQL Syntax for left outer join inside the Tableau, but it never works. I'm trying this approach because the "LEFT OUTER JOIN" takes a lot of time (hours) for processing the information as my collections are in gigabytes.

The error which i keep getting everytime from Tableau SQL is here:

An error occurred while communicating with MongoDB BI Connector.

> Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source.
>   [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.7.0]parse sql 'SELECT *
>   FROM (
>     SELECT *, video_docs
>     FROM videos
>     WHERE video_docs IN (SELECT *
>     FROM video_authors
>     WHERE author_name= videos.author);
>   ) Custom SQL Query
>   LIMIT 0' error: syntax error at position 147

[image]

The BI connector is working fine as per the documentation, but still it says me that this is the parsing error.

My SQL query equivalent for the Mongo shell

Mongo Shell Query, it works perfect!

```
db.videos.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "video_authors",
         localField: "author",
         foreignField: "author_name",
         as: "video_docs"
       }
  }
])
```

SQL Query, never works

```
SELECT *, video_docs
FROM videos
WHERE video_docs IN (SELECT *
FROM video_authors
WHERE author_name= videos.author);
```

I'm following this reference from Mongodb.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-a-single-equality-join-with-lookup

Any help would be appreciated!

Regards,

Adnan

Comment: Make sure you put the text of that message in the body of the question so it is searchable and copyable.

Comment: Thanks @jdv, its updated!